# Rendering bs4.Tag's text with Django Templates

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to render the text from bs4 Tags using Django Template Language.

For some reason bs4.Tag.text isn't accessible from template. I can render it's text only if I get it before and pass itself to template instead of Tag object.

Here is code that I used:

```
from django.template import Template, Context

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_string = '<p>Some text.</p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
tag = soup.find('p')
template = Template('{{ tag.text }} - {{ tag_text }}')
context = Context({'tag': tag, 'tag_text': tag.text})
print(template.render(context))
```

Expected output:
`Some text. - Some text.`

Actual output:
`- Some text.`

I feel confused a bit. For my purposes it's necessary to pass raw bs4.Tag objects to extract text and other attributes after. Hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing a custom templatetag for this.

app/templatetags/bstags.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_attr(obj, attr):
    return getattr(obj, attr)
```

and then in templates call it as:

```
{% load bstags %}
{{ tag|get_attr:text }}
```